# table query mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This is so basic and i can't figure out why it won't work.  i asume it has to do with the fetch_mysql_array($row). here is my code and $user_id is set:

```
$posts=mysql_query("SELECT title, description FROM posts WHERE user_id = '$user_id'") or die(mysql_error()) ;

while ($row=fetch_mysql_array($posts, MYSQL_NUM)) {

for ($i=0;$i < count($row); $i++) {

    echo $row[$i]."&nbsp;";

}

    echo"<br /> <br />";                
}
```

thanks in advance for any help...

Comment: Should it be `mysql_fetch_array`?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Using a PHP editor, you can hardly have such problems like writing `fetch_mysql_array` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`. They show you the options (function, parameters and so) you have automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `mysql_fetch_array`; not `fetch_mysql_array`, which you shouldn't be using anyway. `mysql_` functions are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

You also don't need the `for` loop inside the `while` loop.

Comment: thanks but mysql_* still works, i plan on going back and learning mysqli later